# Canvas line strokethickness with double value creates moire effect

Tags: wpf, canvas, drawing, double, line

I am trying to draw a waveform.
I have a precalculated amount of datapoints I want to draw (for instance 1000). 
I want to fill the full width of my canvas control with the waveform.
Therefore I have to recalculate the width of every datapoint that I draw.

To do this I tried to set the StrokeThickness to the total width divided by the nr of datapoints. (so for instance 0.35629) and **print a line of 0.35629 pixels wide every 0.35629 pixels.**

**This creates an unwanted moire effect.**

To me it feels weird that the StrokeThickness is a double, because how will WPF draw a line of 0.35629 pixels wide?

Below a code example to show what I mean. The first half is ok, the second half has the moire effect.

Is this the way to go or do I need another approach?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    Line line = new Line();
    line.X1 = i;
    line.X2 = i;
    line.Y1 = 0;
    line.Y2 = 100;
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    line.StrokeThickness = 1;
    this.demoCanvas.Children.Add(line);
}

const double canvasWidth = 525;
const double nrOfDatapoints = 500d;
const double pixelsPerPoint = canvasWidth/nrOfDatapoints  ;
double x = 500;
for (int i = 0; i < nrOfDatapoints; i++)
{
    Line line = new Line();
    line.X1 = x;
    line.X2 = x;
    line.Y1 = 0;
    line.Y2 = 100;
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    line.StrokeThickness = pixelsPerPoint;
    this.demoCanvas.Children.Add(line);
    x += pixelsPerPoint;
}
```

Comment: Can you set the canvas to a static size and then put the canvas inside another container and allow the container scale it?  I'm not sure if that would solve the problem or just make a different one.

Comment: This would not fix my problem since I'm also "painting" text onto my canvas, I don't want to get that distorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid moire you should set SnapToDevicePixels="True". [Check it out here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx)

Comment: That got rid of the moire pattern (thanks!). 

Unfortunately it introduced another issue that can be seen in my example code: every x lines a line is not snapped to the following pixel, creating a gap of one pixel. 

Another strategy that I thought of was to recalculate my data input by "creating / removing  a  line every x lines" so I have as many datapoints as I have pixels

Comment: @RichardCook as far as i know i didnt solve this issue, the project i used this on has gone to the fridge, if you have a fix, feel free to post it though